# How to get all Default sites of a SharePoint using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, site

I have tried to getting all the sites of the tenant but I can able to get all Site Collection as well as the Sub Site.

But I can't get the Default site like CompliancePolicyCenter, fundamental_donotdelete_{GUID}, and so on.

Is there any sort of idea or solution to retrieve these site using CSOM ?